# Summation of function inputs in excel

Tags: excel, database, excel-formula, addition, spreadsheet

I have been playing with the Fourier Series, to be precise, Fast Fourier Transform.

These are the parametric coordinates for my to-be-made graph. (I'll explain this shortly)

[image: Latex please :((]

The x,y,z have list inputs as shown below:

---

[image: Pickachuuuuuu]

Here, t varies from 0 to 1

Basically what the x[1] does is pick the *first* element from the table (This is a desmos table and item selection protocol)

**What I want to do:**
I want to make an excel sheet do the same thing. In short, I want to find the summation from (n=1) upto (n=1000) of function a*f(b*t+c) [where a, b and c are variables given as x,y,z in the spreadsheet and f is the sine or cosine function] at evenly spaced out time intervals in a single cells using the least possible number of formulas.

**What I have done so far and problems faced:**

Created an excel sheet with inputs of x,y,z ; I am stuck at how to implement the summation without a lot of hassle, I know how to make t progress with an interval as small as 0.00...01 and put it on the sheet but I am not able to implement the summation so that I directly get the (x,y) in table form. What I thought was to do it manually for *dt*=0.1, i.e. keeping t fixed but x,y,z progressing and then find a summation of all the outputs, but in this way the (x,y) are very imprecise, and obviously doing it manually for t=0.00001 would be not so intelligent if one has a work around.

**A sample dataset for clarity:**
[image: Sample]

Here, I wanted to have **Row 17** directly.

Comment: If someone wants to know why: Desmos has imposed restrictions such that I cannot have a summation of greater than 1000 terms, (one may give a recommendation of how to bypass it in comments)

Comment: Your precise Excel problem is not clear to me at least.

Comment: @SJR if you've read all that, then, in summary I want to find sigma(n=1)^(n=1000) of function a*f(b*t+c) \[where a, b and c are variables given as x,y,z in the spreadsheet] at evenly spaced out time intervals in a single cell using the least possible number of formulas, clear?

Comment: Can you link to the dataset?

Comment: @jblood94 http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=02152328901347454865  , BYPASS any warnings on this site, your computer will open in protected view (the file is in xlsx format made on MS2016)

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi Sorry. I meant the x1, y1, z1 dataset (1000 x 3).

Comment: @jblood94 the desmos link? the pikachu data? https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wyuubnzylg

Comment: Yes. It would be nice to test my solution.

Comment: @jblood94 WAIT, I'll provide in xlsx form

Comment: @jblood94 http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=08889036663611297523 look in the **iron man coefficients sheet**, the plot should look close to this -->https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ujfwlkmka4


This data set has less data so that it's easier for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps I took with dt = 0.001 (1001 parametric coordinates):

1. Put the x1, y1, z1 data into `A2:C1001`
2. Put the values of t into column `E` starting with `E2`
3. In Formulas > Name Manager, create the following variables: `x` = `2*PI()*TRANSPOSE($A$2:$A$1001)`; `y` = `TRANSPOSE($B$2:$B$1001)`; `z` = `PI()*TRANSPOSE($C$2:$C$1001)/180`
4. Column `F` will hold the first dimension of the parametric coordinates. Select `F2:F1002` and enter this CSE formula (commit with `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`): `=MMULT(y*cos(x*E2:E1002+z),--(ROW(A2:A1001)>0))`
5. Column `G` will hold the second dimension of the parametric coordinates. Select `G2:G1002` and enter this CSE formula: `=MMULT(y*sin(x*E2:E1002+z),--(ROW(A2:A1001)>0))`

UPDATE:
Simpler formulas for steps 4 and 5 that don't require CSE (also, this wouldn't require `TRANSPOSE` in the named range definitions):

4. In `F2`: `=SUMPRODUCT(y,COS(x*$E2+z))`, then fill down
5. In `G2`: `=SUMPRODUCT(y,SIN(x*$E2+z))`, then fill down

Comment: Can you also upload your sheet on the same website if not any other?

Comment: @Anindya Prithvi http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=08641327135985134872

Comment: Perfecta, also, can you share a source where I could refer to such advanced functionalities of excel?

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi Actually, it doesn't need to be as complicated as I made it on the first go--I added an update to the answer.